# GraphQL useLazyQuery not working properly when onClick

Tags: reactjs, graphql, onclick

I quite new to GraphQL. I'm trying to use useLazyQuery hook for my onBtnClick function. The button supposed to query and do something everytime on click.

The first time i click on the button the data return is undefined, only second try onwards then it works. This is some sample code below:

```
const [getItemList, { loading, data}] = useLazyQuery(ItemList, { fetchPolicy: 'network-only' });

const onBtnClick = () => {

    getItemList();

    if (loading) {
        //do something
    });
    if (data) {
        //do another thing
    }
}

return (
    <div>
        <button onClick={onBtnClick}>Something</button>
    </div>
)
```

Could anyone guide me or explain on this?

Answer (score 1):

Cause data in `onBtnClick`  function is not newest data. You need a `useEffect` to listen `data` and `loading` change.

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(data, loading)
}, [data, loading])
```